# How to work with headers in server 401 response

Tags: javascript, get, digest-authentication, response-headers

Server is using digest auth method, i make a request and get 401 response, in nonce of WWW-Authenticate field I got what I need to perform a second auth request, but can't extract it to work.

```
async function doRequest() {
    let response = await fetch('URL', {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            Accept: '*/*',
        },
    })

    alert(response.headers.get('Content-Type'));
}
```

How to operate these headers?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
async function doRequest() {
    let response = await fetch('URL', {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            Accept: '*/*',
        },
    })
return response;
}

doRequest()
  .then(response => alert(response.headers.get('Content-Type')););
```

Comment: got "null" in this case